# ISO-3 of all the countries in R

Tags: r, leaflet, raster

I am trying to make a map that looks like [image: this] so where can I get the ISO-3 of all the countries. many thanks in advance.

Comment: Seyma Kalay, does my answer address your question? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
countries <- ne_countries()
countries@data[["iso_a3"]]
```

More info about the package `rnaturalearth`: https://docs.ropensci.org/rnaturalearth/articles/rnaturalearth.html